# Connecting with Google Books API

Tags: android-intent, google-books

I'm working on a class project and since I'm new to web APIs on Android, I've asked around looking for a sample Google books Intent that I can use in my Android project. I even tried using JSON but have no clue as to how to go on. I'll love it if anyone can help me with a sample Google code Android class to just fetch content using uri.

Answer (score 4):

you must register to google API and get **API key**

https://code.google.com/apis/console/?pli=1#project:713668701465

in **services** link => **ON** Books API

in **API Access** link => under Simple API Access get **API KEY**

And follow this instructions

https://developers.google.com/books/

ex: www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=isbn:1419705849&key={your api key}